# How to create dialog box with text in list box from an existing dialog box using Win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to create a modal Dialog Box (dialog2) from Dialog Box(dialog1) so that List Box(listbox2) from the dialog2 would have a string from List Box(listbox1) from a dialog 1.

I tried:
1) To get a string from listbox1 inside a dialog1 and set it to listbox2 inside dlgproc1 
2) To save string from listbox1 into global variable and set this string to listbox2 in dlgproc2 under WM_INITDIALOG case
3) To get a string from dialog1 listbox1 from a dialog2 proc function Dlg2Proc, and then set it to listbox2.

Here is example of last attempt:

```
static wchar_t* buf;
HINSTANCE hInstGl;
int nCmdShow;

BOOL CALLBACK Dlg2Proc(HWND hwndlg2, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:{
        int len = SendDlgItemMessage((HWND)lParam, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)0, 0);
        if (len > 0) {
            buf = (wchar_t*)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
            SendDlgItemMessage((HWND)lParam, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)buf);
            SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf);
            free(buf);
        }
    }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hwndlg2, 0);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwndlg1, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Message) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case IDC_ADD:{
                    int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwndlg1, IDC_TEXT));
                if (len > 0) {
                    buf = (wchar_t*)malloc(len + 1);
                    GetDlgItemText(hwndlg1, IDC_TEXT, buf, len + 1);
                    SendDlgItemMessage(hwndlg1, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
            }
                break;
            case IDC_VIEW:
                    DialogBoxParam(hInstGl, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), hwndlg1, Dlg2Proc, (LPARAM)hwndlg1);
                break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hwndlg1, 0);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    nCmdShow = iCmdShow;
    hInstGl = hInst;
    return DialogBox(hInstGl, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DlgProc);
}
```

Here are controls propeties from Resource script file:

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "View",IDC_VIEW,198,155,50,14
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,7,46,295,101,LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_EXTENDEDSEL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_TEXT,7,14,295,26,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Add",IDC_ADD,254,156,48,13
END

IDD_DIALOG2 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 156
 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2,7,7,295,142,LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_EXTENDEDSEL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END
```

I expect a string in listbox2, but the result of all approaches is dialog2 with EMPTY listbox2 in it.

I am new to programming but did some research to this particular problem for several days but couldn't find exact answer. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: 
After doing debugging near line:
    `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf);`
i see "**Unable to read memory**" message corresponding to `hwndlg2` variable.

**SOLVED**:
Needed to replace
`SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf);`
with
`SendDlgItemMessage(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)buf);`

Comment: A few thinks that look weird: 1. why `ShowWindow(hwndlg2, SW_HIDE);`? 2. `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg1, IDC_LIST2, buf);` but I'd guess that there is no list2 in dlg1, is it? 3. The return of `LB_GETTEXTLEN` is a `TCHAR` count and you seem to be using `UNICODE` compilation, so you must allocate with `malloc((len+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)`.

Comment: @rodrigo 1. and 3. - my bad, you are right, but for 2.: what should i add to 1st arg in **SetDlgItemText()** ?  I tried **GetDlgItem(hwndlg1, IDD_DIALOG2)** but to the same result. Also if i try **GetDlgItem(hwndlg2, IDD_DIALOG2)** i get error cause **hwndlg2** isn't defined yet.

Comment: If list2 is in dlg2, then you must write `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2`, any other combination will not work. But you cannot access dlg2 before calling `DialogBox(...IDD_DIALOG2)` because it just does not exist. What you can do is to access dlg1 from dlg2. Anyway the standard way to pass arguments to a dialog is to use `DialogBoxParam()` that has an extra `LPARAM` argument that you can point to the arguments: this value is received as the `LPARAM` in `WM_INIT_DIALOG`.

Comment: @rodrigo what exact entity should be passed to the last argument of `DialogBoxParam()` in this case?

Comment: You can pass whatever you want. You can pass the `buf` pointer, a pointer to a local struct with many values, the handle of dlg1...

Comment: @rodrigo if  i pass `buf` to `DialogBoxParam()`, then what should be in `Dlg2Proc()` ? I try to do this: `case WM_INITDIALOG:
  switch (HIWORD(lParam)) {}`. If it is right approach then what should be in `case` options inside `switch` statement?

Comment: @rodrigo i think i figured out what you explained. i passed handle to dlg1 in `DialogBoxParam()`, and then called `SendDlgItemMessage((HWND)lParam, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)buf)` from `Dlg2Proc`. So i got string in buf, and after this i called `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf)` and still no effect. Listbox in Dialog2 is empty.

Comment: If you are confident that `buf` has the right contents, (use a debugger or a plain `wprintf`) and the text still doesn't show, then chances are that your controls are wrong. Try doing `GetDlgItem(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2)` and check for `NULL`. Also, you can try the very useful `spy++` to check what really are in your windows.

Comment: @rodrigo Yep, buf is filled with right contents. I will update the question and try to debug code. Thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you can post the contents of your .rc file, too.

Comment: `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf)` is trying to set the text of a list box, which makes no sense. A list box has items, and each item has text, but the list box itself has no text.

Comment: @RaymondChen I replaced `SetDlgItemText(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, buf)` with `SendDlgItemMessage(hwndlg2, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)buf)` and now it finally works. Thanks a lot! But still don't get the difference between these two calls.

Comment: A list box contains items. The items have text. The list box itself does not have text. (Your phone has a SIM, maybe two. The SIM has a phone number. The phone doesn't have a phone number.)